# Rails not loading .less files with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I've been running Twitter Bootstrap successfully for months on my Rails 3.2.1 app

I did a push to Heroku and the push failed on assets:precompile and the whole app crashed

Running assets:precompile locally also failed with the following error:

```
no such file to load -- less
(in /blah/blah/app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less)
```

There have been no changes to my bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less or bootstrap_defaults.css.less files, but I suspect there has been a Gem update (how can I tell?)

I have managed partial recovery by ADDING the gems:

```
gem 'less-rails-bootstrap'
gem 'therubyracer'
```

(rubyracer being required by the other gem)

I also did a rails g bootstrap:install -f and reinstated any custom lines in bootstrap_and_overrides from a backup

I also reverted to a Git commit from where I knew it was working

However, I have only partial success - with some site CSS styling now different than originally

What is it that has happened here? And how can I go back to my original setup?

Comment: So everything was working and then one day it just stopped on its own? What did you change in between the last known working revision and the current one? If you're using Bundler then gems shouldn't update without you doing this explicitly. Maybe a git diff might help you track down what changed.

Comment: I'm beyond confusion with this.Since the last push to Heroku I've written a ton of code on my local machine, all working ok and none referencing Bootstrap. Then I do a push to Heroku and bang, fails on assets precompile. Try assets:precompile locally & fails too. My code backups show that it could run Bootstrap on only gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', but its website says it needs more than that. Sorry, I cant even describe it coherently now

Comment: What error did you get during the Heroku push? There are a few very common ones.

Comment: Finally I have it working. Initially it was the error in the question above. For reasons I don't yet know, I needed to add gem 'less-rails-bootstrap' and gem 'therubyracer' in addition to gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'. Then error changed to missing @fontAwesomeEotPath_iefix. Then I ran rails g bootstrap:install -f. This I think added application.css back into the app (as well as losing code from the bootstrap files which I got back from backup), so had to delete application.css from git & change some requires. Still dont know what happened. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Yeah that's very weird. I use bootstrap in a few rails apps and I don't need less-rails-bootstrap. The twitter-bootstrap-rails gems add the less-rails gem as a dependency, and that's all I've ever needed. In any case, glad it's working for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Even though your problem is resolved, I just want to add this for anyone else who runs into the same error: In my case, I simply needed to restart my server. I had added three related gems to my Gemfile (less-rails, therubyracer, and twitter-bootstrap-rails) while my local server was running, resulting in the same problem seen above. So once I shut it down and restarted it again, everything loaded well.